# Custom sorting by month name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-server-2012

I have a table where for some dates a certain number of entries are placed. Here is the table structure :

```
ID  EntryName     Entries   DateOfEntry
1       A           20      2016-01-17
2       B           22      2016-01-29
3       C           23      2016-02-17
4       D           19      2016-02-17
5       E           29      2016-03-17
6       F           30      2016-03-17
7       G           43      2016-04-17
8       H           10      2016-04-17
9       I           5       2016-05-17
10      J           120     2016-05-17
11      K           220     2016-06-17
12      L           210     2016-06-17
13      M           10      2016-07-17
14      N           20      2016-07-17
15      O           15      2016-08-17
16      P           17      2016-08-17
17      Q           19      2016-09-17
18      R           23      2016-09-17
19      S           43      2016-10-17
20      T           56      2016-10-17
21      U           65      2016-11-17
22      V           78      2016-11-17
23      W           12      2016-12-17
24      X           23      2016-12-17
25      Y           43      2016-02-17
26      Z           67      2016-03-17
27      AA          35      2015-01-17
28      AB          23      2015-01-29
29      AC          43      2015-02-17
30      AD          35      2015-02-17
31      AE          45      2015-03-17
32      AF          23      2015-03-17
33      AG          43      2015-04-17
34      AH          19      2015-04-17
35      AI          21      2015-05-17
36      AJ          13      2015-05-17
37      AK          22      2015-06-17
38      AL          45      2015-06-17
39      AM          66      2015-07-17
40      AN          77      2015-07-17
41      AO          89      2015-08-17
42      AP          127     2015-08-17
43      AQ          19      2015-09-17
44      AR          223     2015-09-17
45      AS          143     2015-10-17
46      AT          36      2015-10-17
47      AU          45      2015-11-17
48      AV          28      2015-11-17
49      AW          72      2015-12-17
50      AX          24      2015-12-17
51      AY          46      2015-02-17
52      AZ          62      2015-03-17
```

The column `EntryName` is the entry identifier, the column `Entries` has the total number of entries for the date specified in the column `DateOfEntry`.

I am trying to formulate a query where the total number of entries are displayed on a month-wise basis. I currently have this query :

```
SELECT      DateName(MONTH, e.DateOfEntry) AS MonthOfEntry,
            MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) AS MonthNumber,
            SUM(e.Entries) AS TotalEntries
FROM        #entry e
GROUP BY    MONTH(e.DateOfEntry), DateName(MONTH,e.DateOfEntry)
ORDER BY    MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) ASC
```

which works fine as far as displaying the results are concerned. However, my issue here is that I need to sort the results on a month-wise basis where the starting month would be dynamic i.e. arising from a parameter (*supplied by the user*).

**This means that if the user selects May of 2015 the results should be sorted from May 2015 to April 2016. Similarly, if the user selects October 2015, the results would be displayed from October 2015 to September 2016.**

How would I go about getting this condition within the `ORDER BY` clause ?

Comment: You wouldn't... you also need a where clause `Where DateofEntry between  Date provided and dateprovided+1 year order by DateofEntry Asc` As it seems like you only want 1 year of records.... use a between.

Comment: @xQbert That would only remove the records outside the boundary. That isn't my issue. I can do that easily. Its about sorting them after.

Comment: Why wouldn't `order by year(E.DateofEntry) asc, Month(E.DateofEntry) Asc` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Of all the answers and suggestions I have come across here, I find this way (*suggested by xQbert in the question's comments*) to be the simplest one** :

```
SELECT      DateName(MONTH, e.DateOfEntry) + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), YEAR(e.DateOfEntry)) AS MonthOfEntry,
            MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) AS MonthNumber,
            SUM(e.Entries) AS TotalEntries
FROM        Entry e
WHERE       e.DateOfEntry BETWEEN @StartDate AND (DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @StartDate))
GROUP BY    MONTH(e.DateOfEntry), DateName(MONTH,e.DateOfEntry), YEAR(e.DateOfEntry)
ORDER BY    YEAR(e.DateOfEntry) ASC, MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) ASC
```

A fiddle to demonstrate this : http://rextester.com/CJFFP5640

Initially, I was using the following query :

```
SELECT      sortingList.MonthOfEntry,
            sortingList.TotalEntries,
            sortingList.MonthNumber
FROM        (
              SELECT            DateName(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(e.DateOfEntry), 0) - 1) + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(20),YEAR(e.DateOfEntry)) AS MonthOfEntry,
                                SUM(e.Entries) as TotalEntries,
                                CASE
                                    WHEN    ((MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) - MONTH(@StartDate)) > 0)
                                    THEN    (MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) - MONTH(@StartDate)) + 1
                                    WHEN    ((MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) - MONTH(@StartDate)) = 0)
                                    THEN    1
                                    ELSE 
                                            ((12 - MONTH(@StartDate)) + (MONTH(e.DateOfEntry))) + 1
                                END
                                AS MonthNumber
              FROM              Entry e
              WHERE             e.DateOfEntry >= @StartDate AND e.DateOfEntry < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @StartDate)
              GROUP BY          DateName(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(e.DateOfEntry), 0) - 1), YEAR(e.DateOfEntry), MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) - MONTH(@StartDate), MONTH(e.DateOfEntry)
            ) sortingList
ORDER BY    sortingList.MonthNumber ASC
```

Here's an Fiddle to demonstrate this : http://rextester.com/LEVD30653

**Explanation (non TL;DR)**

You can see that it's essentially the same `WHERE` clause. However, the query at the top uses much simpler logic for sorting and is more fluent and readable.

Do note that the second solution (using the `CASE` statement) sorts the month numbers as per the user-provided month number i.e. if the user provides December 2015, then the second solution will number Dec 2015 as 1, January 2016 as 2, February 2016 as 3 and so on and so forth. This might be more beneficial in cases where you want to work on top of this data.

As far as my use-case is concerned, this makes more sense. However, as far as the scope of the question is concerned, the query at the top is the best one.

Answer (score 2):

You can put an offset into the `ORDER BY` using modulo arithmetic.  For April:

```
ORDER BY (MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) + 12 - 4) % 12
--------------------------------------^ month number to start with
```

(The `+ 12` is simply so I don't have to remember if `%` returns negative numbers with negative operands.)

If you want the results chronologically, you can instead do:

```
ORDER BY MIN(e.DateOfEntry)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly

"This means that if the user selects May of 2015 the results should be sorted from May 2015 to April 2016. Similarly, if the user selects October 2015, the results would be displayed from October 2015 to September 2016."

this should work:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#entry') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #entry;

CREATE TABLE #entry(ID INT ,EntryName  VARCHAR(10)  , Entries  INT ,  DateOfEntry DATE);

INSERT INTO #entry (ID  ,EntryName     ,Entries   ,DateOfEntry)
VALUES
(1 ,'A', 20     ,'2016-01-17'),
(2 ,'B', 22     ,'2016-01-29'),
(3 ,'C', 23     ,'2016-02-17'),
(4 ,'D', 19     ,'2016-02-17'),
(5 ,'E', 29     ,'2016-03-17'),
(6 ,'F', 30     ,'2016-03-17'),
(7 ,'G', 43     ,'2016-04-17'),
(8 ,'H', 10     ,'2016-04-17'),
(9 ,'I', 5      ,'2016-05-17'),
(10,'J', 120    ,'2016-05-17'),
(11,'K', 220    ,'2016-06-17'),
(12,'L', 210    ,'2016-06-17'),
(13,'M', 10     ,'2016-07-17'),
(14,'N', 20     ,'2016-07-17'),
(15,'O', 15     ,'2016-08-17'),
(16,'P', 17     ,'2016-08-17'),
(17,'Q', 19     ,'2016-09-17'),
(18,'R', 23     ,'2016-09-17'),
(19,'S', 43     ,'2016-10-17'),
(20,'T', 56     ,'2016-10-17'),
(21,'U', 65     ,'2016-11-17'),
(22,'V', 78     ,'2016-11-17'),
(23,'W', 12     ,'2016-12-17'),
(24,'X', 23     ,'2016-12-17'),
(25,'Y', 43     ,'2016-02-17'),
(26,'Z', 67     ,'2016-03-17'),
(27,'AA',35     ,'2015-01-17'),
(28,'AB',23     ,'2015-01-29'),
(29,'AC',43     ,'2015-02-17'),
(30,'AD',35     ,'2015-02-17'),
(31,'AE',45     ,'2015-03-17'),
(32,'AF',23     ,'2015-03-17'),
(33,'AG',43     ,'2015-04-17'),
(34,'AH',19     ,'2015-04-17'),
(35,'AI',21     ,'2015-05-17'),
(36,'AJ',13     ,'2015-05-17'),
(37,'AK',22     ,'2015-06-17'),
(38,'AL',45     ,'2015-06-17'),
(39,'AM',66     ,'2015-07-17'),
(40,'AN',77     ,'2015-07-17'),
(41,'AO',89     ,'2015-08-17'),
(42,'AP',127    ,'2015-08-17'),
(43,'AQ',19     ,'2015-09-17'),
(44,'AR',223    ,'2015-09-17'),
(45,'AS',143    ,'2015-10-17'),
(46,'AT',36     ,'2015-10-17'),
(47,'AU',45     ,'2015-11-17'),
(48,'AV',28     ,'2015-11-17'),
(49,'AW',72     ,'2015-12-17'),
(50,'AX',24     ,'2015-12-17'),
(51,'AY',46     ,'2015-02-17'),
(52,'AZ',62     ,'2015-03-17')
```

QUERY WITH PARAMS:

```
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(2) = '05', @Year VARCHAR(4) = '2015'

SELECT      DateName(MONTH, e.DateOfEntry) AS MonthOfEntry,
            MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) AS MonthNumber,
            SUM(e.Entries) AS TotalEntries
FROM        #entry e
WHERE CAST(e.DateOfEntry AS DATE) >= CAST( @Year+@Month+'01' AS DATE)
GROUP BY    MONTH(e.DateOfEntry), DateName(MONTH,e.DateOfEntry)
ORDER BY    MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) ASC
```

RESULTS:

[image]

Comment: Very close, however, there are no results for the month of Jan, Feb etc. Having said that, your idea is in the right direction. :)

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny oh sorry about that it is a silly mistake. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use the belosw in order by

```
  ORDER BY YEAR(e.DATEOFENTRY),    
  DATEPART(MM,e.DAREOFENTRY)
```

This will sort the result first for Year and next for month.

Here you need to specify these same columns in Select.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parameter is an Integer called @FirstMonth, you could get the proper month order using:

Case

```
  WHEN MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) < @FirstMonth then MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) + 12

   ELSE MONTH(e.DateOfEntry)

END AS MonthNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

add a where clause for the query

```
WHERE MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) < User.Month AND YEAR(e.DateOfEntry) < User.Year AND  MONTH(e.DateOfEntry) > (User.Month-1) AND YEAR(e.DateOfEntry) > (User.Year+1)
```